# Rails where query chain with or for array input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I want to create a query chain in order to find my bot users given specific filters. Some filters can have multiple values. For example, my "locale" filter can have multiple values (fr_FR, en_US for example).

In this example, I check two locales checkboxes (fr_FR and en_US).

I created a query chain but the output is not what I want:

> SELECT "bot_users".* FROM "bot_users" WHERE ("bot_users"."core_bot_id"
>   = ? AND (locale = 'fr_FR') OR "bot_users"."core_bot_id" = ? AND (locale = 'fr_FR') AND (locale = 'en_EN'))  [["core_bot_id", 1],
>   ["core_bot_id", 1]]

I would like something like this:

> SELECT "bot_users".* FROM "bot_users" WHERE ("bot_users"."core_bot_id"
>   = ? AND (locale = 'fr_FR' OR 'en_EN'))  [["core_bot_id", 1]]

Here is the code:

```
@filter = Filter.find_by_letter_id(@letter.id)
        $i = 1
        $a = 1
        $s = 1
        query = [{first_name: @filter.first_name}, {last_name: @filter.last_name}, {source: @filter.segment}, {gender: @filter.gender}, {timezone: @filter.timezone}, {locale: @filter.locale}, {created_at: [@filter.creation_date_start, @filter.creation_date_finish]}]
        query_chain = BotUser.where(core_bot_id: @bot.id)

          query.each do |hash|
            hash.each_pair do |key, value|
              if value.present? == true
                  if key.to_s == "timezone"
                    while  $i < value.size do
                      query_chain = query_chain.where("timezone = ?", value[$i].to_f)
                      $i += 1
                    end
                  elsif key.to_s == "locale"
                    while  $a < value.size do
                      puts $a.to_s
                      if $a == 1
                        query_chain = query_chain.where("locale = ?", value[$a])
                      else
                        query_chain = query_chain.or(query_chain.where("locale = ?", value[$a]))
                      end
                      $a += 1
                    end
                  elsif key.to_s == "gender"
                      query_chain = query_chain.where("gender = ?", value)
                  elsif key.to_s == "core_bot_id"
                      query_chain = query_chain.where("core_bot_id = ?", value)
                  elsif key.to_s == "created_at"
                    if value[0].present? == true and value[1].present? == true
                      query_chain = query_chain.where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', value[0], value[1].end_of_day)
                    elsif value[0].present? == true
                      query_chain = query_chain.where('created_at > ?', value[0])
                    elsif value[1].present? == true
                      query_chain = query_chain.where('created_at < ?', value[1].end_of_day)
                    end
                  else
                    query_chain = query_chain.where("#{key} = ?", value)
                  end
                end
              end
          end
```

## UPDATE, trying Jaril method:

### Controller:

```
private

    def filter_params
      params.fetch(:query, {}).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :timezone, :gender)
    end

    def set_nb_recipients
    @filter = Filter.find_by_letter_id(@letter.id)


filter_params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
 query: {
        core_bot_id: @bot.id,
        first_name:  @filter.first_name,
        last_name: @filter.last_name,
        source: @filter.segment,
        gender: @filter.gender,
        timezone: @filter.timezone,
        locale: @filter.locale,
        creation_date_start: @filter.creation_date_start,
        creation_date_finish: @filter.creation_date_finish
      }
    })
    query = FilterQuery.new(filter_params)

            query = FilterQuery.new(filter_params)
            @bot_users = query.execute || BotUser.none

            @nb_users = @bot_users.length
     end
```

### app/models/filter_query.rb

```
class FilterQuery

  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :timezone, :gender, :locale, :core_bot_id, :source, :creation_date_start, :creation_date_finish

  validates :gender, inclusion: { in: %w(male female) }

  def initialize(params)
    super(params)
  end

  def execute
    return false unless valid?
    @bot_users = BotUser.where(core_bot_id: core_bot_id)
    @bot_users = @bot_users.where('first_name LIKE ?', "#{first_name}%") if first_name.present?
    @bot_users = @bot_users.where('last_name LIKE ?', "#{last_name}%") if last_name.present?
    @bot_users = @bot_users.where(timezone: timezone) if timezone.present?
    @bot_users = @bot_users.where(timezone: locale) if locale.present?
    @bot_users = @bot_users.where(gender: gender) if gender.present?
    @bot_users = @bot_users.where(source: source) if source.present?
    @bot_users = @bot_users.where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', creation_date_start, creation_date_finish) if creation_date_start.present? and creation_date_finish.present?
    @bot_users = @bot_users.where('created_at > ?', creation_date_start) if creation_date_start.present? and creation_date_finish.present? == false
    @bot_users = @bot_users.where('created_at < ?', creation_date_finish) if creation_date_start.present? == false and creation_date_finish.present?
    @bot_users
  end

end
```

Unfortunately, this does not return anything. I'm not sure about the params part, could you help me with that? I store the data in a database and get the params from the object.

Comment: the SQL you are looking for is `IN()` and can easily be `where(locale: ['fr_FR','en_EN'])` which will produce `locale IN('fr_FR','en_EN')` which is essentially an `OR` statement

Comment: Oh! This works perfectly well, thank you very much!! I didn't know about this "IN" feature...

Comment: Did you read my comments on @Jaryl's post `execute` method should end with `@bot_users` otherwise you will get a `nil` response unless (in your case) this condition is true `if creation_date_start.present? == false and creation_date_finish.present?`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by adding @bot_users at the end of the method? Just like I put it now (see updated question)

Comment: Yes just like that

Comment: I updated my question, I create the filter_params but get the following error: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError. However, it seems I permit those parameters...

Comment: That sounds like a new and different question. Since this one appears to be solved feel free to post a new question with your new issue if you cannot resolve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm with Jaryl.

Less `if/elsif`. What you're looking for is [case](https://www.skorks.com/2009/08/how-a-ruby-case-statement-works-and-what-you-can-do-with-it/). And since a bunch of your queries have similar structure, you can stuff those into the `else` clause of the `case` statement.

Less `if x? == true`. If `x` has a question mark, then it's already returning a `true` or `false`. You don't have to say, `if true == true`. Just say, `if x?`. Like, `if value[0].present?`. Depending on your specific requirements, you **may** be able to skip the `present?` part, as well. If you're just trying to guard against `nil` values, then you could just do `if value[0]`. However, as engineersmnky points out in the comments, if you want to guard against empty strings, hashes, and arrays - then you'll need to stick with `if value[0].present?`. And remember, you can always stick your `if` statement at the end of a single line if you're not going to do an `else`. Like:

```
query_chain = query_chain.where('created_at > ?', value[0]) if value[0].present?
```

Less type conversion (`key.to_s`). Just compare the key variable to another key. Why convert it to a string?

Less looping. Especially with those iteration variables and value comparisons (`while $i < value.size`) - yucky! This:

```
while  $i < value.size do
  query_chain = query_chain.where("timezone = ?", value[$i].to_f)
  $i += 1
end
```

Is not idiomatic. Better would be:

```
value.each do |timezone|
  query_chain = query_chain.where("timezone = ?", timezone.to_f)
end
```

Of course, you could make that query a little less verbose:

```
value.each do |timezone|
  query_chain = query_chain.where(timezone: timezone.to_f)
end
```

But, all you're doing in that each loop is converting timezone to_f. So, why not do that in one shot and chain a single query, like:

```
timezones = value.map{|timezone| timezone.to_f}
query_chain = query_chain.where(timezone: timezones)
```

Of course, you could save yourself the temporary variable assignment and just do:

```
query_chain = query_chain.where(timezone: value.map{|timezone| timezone.to_f})
```

If you don't mind the long(ish) line.

I like Jaryl's approach. If you want to stick with your current approach, though, it could look something like:

```
query.each do |hash|
  hash.each_pair do |key, value|
    if value
      case key
      when :timezone
        query_chain = query_chain.where(timezone: value.map{|timezone| timezone.to_f})
      when :created_at
        query_chain = query_chain.where('created_at > ?', value[0]) if value[0]
        query_chain = query_chain.where('created_at < ?', value[1].end_of_day) if value[1]
      else
        query_chain = query_chain.where(key => value)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here's a slightly different implementation of the Jaryl approach...

```
class FilterQuery

  attr_accessor :first_name, 
                :last_name, 
                :timezone, 
                :gender, 
                :locale, 
                :core_bot_id, 
                :source, 
                :creation_date_start, 
                :creation_date_finish

    def initialize(params)
      params.each{|k,v| send("#{k}=",v)}
    end

    def execute
      return false unless valid?
      @bot_users = BotUser.where(core_bot_id: core_bot_id)
      [:first_name, :last_name].each do |var_sym|
        val = send(var_sym)
        @bot_users = @bot_users.where("#{var_sym} LIKE ?", "#{val}%") if val.present?
      end
      [:timezone, :locale, :gender, :source].each do |var_sym|
        val = send(var_sym)
        @bot_users = @bot_users.where(var_sym => val) if val.present?
      end
      @bot_users = @bot_users.where('created_at > ?', creation_date_start) if creation_date_start.present?
      @bot_users = @bot_users.where('created_at < ?', creation_date_finish) if creation_date_finish.present?
      @bot_users
    end

  private

    def valid?
      %w(male female).include? gender
    end

end
```

Comment: Hope it helps. Glad to see you trying out Jaryl's approach! Remember, `if gender`. Not, `if gender.present?`.

Comment: @jvillian `present?` and truthy/falsey are not the same. `present?` is equal to `!blank?` where `blank?` is Object specific and can be delegated to `empty?` as well. e.g. `"".present? #=> false`, `[].present? #=> false`, `{}.present? #=> false` where as standard ruby would state that all of those `Objects` are truthy

Comment: @engineersmnky - Thank you for the correction! I updated the answer with attribution. Hopefully, I got it right this time.

Comment: I couldn't make it work with Jaryl's solution (my understanding of strong params is probably not sufficient enough even if his solution seems really good). Your solution works perfectly well so I mark it as the answer. Again thanks for the explanations!

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, you would want to do all these in a query class. Also, try to tone down on the if/else yeah?

Here's a sample of what that would look like, it's incomplete, but I've thrown in a validation for you for good measure:

```
class FilterQuery

  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :timezone, :gender

  validates :gender, inclusion: { in: %w(male female) }

  def initialize(params)
    super(params)
  end

  def execute
    return false unless valid?
    @bot_users = BotUser.all
    @bot_users = @bot_users.where('first_name LIKE ?', "#{first_name}%") if first_name.present?
    @bot_users = @bot_users.where('last_name LIKE ?', "#{last_name}%") if last_name.present?
    @bot_users = @bot_users.where(timezone: timezone) if timezone.present?
    @bot_users = @bot_users.where(gender: gender) if gender.present?
    @bot_users
  end

end
```

To use it, plop this into your controller:

```
def index
  query = FilterQuery.new(filter_params)
  @bot_users = query.execute || BotUser.none
end

private

def filter_params
  params.fetch(:query, {}).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :timezone, :gender)
end
```

Comment: Only problem is if  `gender` is not present `execute` will return `nil` (regardless of the existence of other parameters). Place `@bot_users` as the last line of `execute` to resolve this

Comment: Also `params.fetch(:query, {}).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :timezone, :gender)` will have an issue if `:query` does not exist because `permit` is not a `Hash` method.you could change this to `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new`

Comment: Could you explain this point please? When I try it, there is no response (no BotUser query performed)

Comment: @engineersmnky that's true, missed that out and didn't test it, but glad he's got it fixed.

Comment: I'm not sure my code fetches the params. How can I wrap the params into :query?

Comment: That depends on how you are making the request. If it is in a form generated by rails, do something like `= form_for :query` and the form generator will wrap the input names like so `query[first_name]`.